# When sorting a list by an int field, can you sort 310 to be between 41 and 39?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have alist of objects I am sorting by their ID field, but the IDs are generated to go 38, 39, 310, 41, 42, etc. Is there a LINQ function to handle this kind of thing?

I tried a post-sort loop, to move around the objects in my list, but it is too much of a performance hit to be a viable solution. I've also tried swapping the IDs from 310 to 40 when I fetch them, and switch them back after the sort, but I was told that was also not viable, in case they start going 39, 310, 40 in the future. I've also asked the other dev if he could switch the ID generation to go from 39 to 40, he told me it's legacy code he doesn't want to touch.

```
data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Number).ThenByDescending(x => x.Value)
```

The current result looks like: 310, 210, 110, 39, 38, etc

I'd like it to look like: 42, 41, 310, 39, 38, ..., 31, 210, 29, etc

Comment: *"I'd like it to look like: 42, 41, 310, 39, 38, ..., 31, 210, 29, etc"* - That looks like *very customized* sorting logic.  So no, neither LINQ nor anything else is going to have a function which already defines your *custom* sorting logic.  You're going to have to define that logic and write code for it.

Comment: Suppose I give you *any* two numbers, x and y.  Please describe for me a simple rule that chooses exactly one of three options: they are equal, x goes before y in the ordering, or x goes after y in the ordering. If you can do that, then the problem can be solved pretty easily, but I don't understand exactly what your rule is.

Comment: Curious when the sequence is 308,309,.....what would be next ?

Comment: 308,309,3100,40,

Comment: " in case they start going 39, 310, 40" - but at *that* point you'll have ambiguous encodings which you don't currently have so a lot more consideration would be required before that should be allowed.

Comment: You can `.ToString()` and it will work,

Comment: @fhnaseer: Sorting by string values will sort 310 next to 31, not next to 39.

Comment: @fhnaseer `new[] { 42, 41, 310, 39, 38 }.OrderBy(i => i.ToString())` produces `310, 38, 39, 41, 42`

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, I believe you have to write your own custom logic for the class. Implement `IComparer` maybe,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you're simply trying to prioritize the first number in the integer, prior to the number as a whole. If so maybe this will work for you?

```
var list = new List<int>() { 210, 29, 42, 310, 39, 38, 41, 31 };
var sortedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.ToString()[0]).ThenByDescending(x => x);

// 42, 41, 310, 39, 38, 31, 210, 29
```

If you do need to support 1010 and 101 as speculated in the comments, it gets a little more complicated but you can still use a similar strategy. Though at this point Dheeraj's solution starts to look more appealing.

```
var list = new List<int>() { 210, 29, 42, 310, 39, 38, 41, 31, 99, 101, 910, 1010 };
var sortedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.ToString().Substring(0, x.Length() - (x % 10 == 0 ? 2 : 1))))
    .ThenByDescending(x => x);

// 1010, 101, 910, 99, 42, 41, 310, 39, 38, 31, 210, 29
```

**IntExtensions.cs**

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int Length(this int value)
    {
        value = Math.Abs(value);
        if (value < 10) return 1;
        if (value < 100) return 2;
        if (value < 1000) return 3;
        if (value < 10000) return 4;
        if (value < 100000) return 5;
        if (value < 1000000) return 6;
        if (value < 10000000) return 7;
        if (value < 100000000) return 8;
        if (value < 1000000000) return 9;
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Unless something drastic changes, there should never be more than 60 of these objects per list, but if that day comes, thanks for the advice there too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IComparer` to sort the list directly.

```
public class LegacyIdDescendingComparer : IComparer<DataClass>
{
    public LegacyIdDescendingComparer() { }

    public int Compare(DataClass x, DataClass y)
    {
        if (x.ID == y.ID)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // The last digit, forgive my naming conventions
        // If the number ends with 10 then the last digit is ten else it is whatever the value in units place
        // I did this to make this work with the following case: 28, 29, 210, 30, 31
        // 210 will be 10, 31 will be 1
        var x_tens = x.ID % 100 == 10 ? 10 : x.ID % 10;
        var y_tens = y.ID % 100 == 10 ? 10 : y.ID % 10;

        // The number divided by 10
        // 210 is 2, 29 is also 2
        var x_quo = x.ID % 100 == 10 ? x.ID / 100 : x.ID / 10;
        var y_quo = y.ID % 100 == 10 ? y.ID / 100 : y.ID / 10;

        if (x_quo > y_quo)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (x_quo == y_quo)
        {
            return y_tens.CompareTo(x_tens);
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can sort the list in descending order by calling Sort on it

```
data.Sort(new LegacyIdDescendingComparer());
```

This will sort the data list in the descending order of `ID`.

You can test it here: https://ideone.com/oKN1Qs

Answer (score 0):

So, if the number is exactly divisible by 10, we should divide by 100, add 1, and multiply by 10 to retrieve the "real" value that would sort naturally<sup>1</sup>:

```
data.OrderByDescending(x => {
  if(x.Number%10!=0) return x.Number;
  return ((x.Number / 100) + 1) * 10;
}).ThenByDescending(x => x.Value)
```

I'm assuming `Number` is `int` and allowing integer division rules to "get rid" of the pesky `0.1` after the division.

<sup>1</sup>That is, 310 should be treated as 40, 510 should be treated as 60, etc.

Comment: What if there are numbers like 3100

Comment: It's not clear from the original question what to do if 311 is in the list; your algorithm doesn't consider that.

Comment: @preciousbetine - if the number pattern repeats as they've shown in the question, we would expect the next number after `3099` to be `30910`, followed by `3101`. We'd never expect to see a `3100` because numbers which should have a `0` in the units position apparently have `10` in the "units" position and have a tens digit one lower than expected.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how your algorithm works if, say, 310 and 40 are both in the list. The sort key for 310 will be 40, and the sort key for 40 will be 10, so doesn't that mean that 310 will be to the left of 40?

Comment: @EricLippert - I'd originally missed that they were speculating that in the future they may have both `310` and `40` be possible. But as I've pointed out to them, that means they start having ambiguous encodings. This answer addresses the encodings they have right now but not that future state.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend splitting the numbers into character arrays and do an initial sort by the first character.

Then parse the remaining characters back to int for the descending sort. Like so

```
string[] id = {"38", "39", "310", "41", "42"}
id.OrderBy(x => x.ToCharArray()[0]).ThenByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Remove(0, 1)))
```

Comment: Your first `OrderBy` should likely be `OrderByDescending`. FYI, it's also not necessary to call ToCharArray().

Comment: I don't understand what the function of `ToCharArray` is here; can you explain? If you have a string and you want the first char, why not just say `x[0]`?

Comment: I also don't understand why you're removing the first character in the `ThenBy`. Surely if we have "310" and "39", then we can just say that 310 is larger than 39; we don't have to figure that out by noting that 10 is larger than 9.

Comment: My syntax knowledge is not very advanced so there is probably a better more streamlined way. The idea is the sort by first character, then remaining value. I am a self-taught C# user, I don't claim to be an expert developer. I figured this would help me learn